# how to get recaptcha client verification parameter g-recaptcha-response after user confirms he is not a robot?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, rest, recaptcha

I am trying to implement Google recaptcha in a form. The form issues an HTTP post request to a server where it sends the for data as a JSON object.

I added Google reCAPTCHA just before the form submit button with the following div tag:

```
     <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="{SITE_KEY}"></div>
```

Also I added the required JavaScript file in the head tag:

```
 <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

Now the submit button issues a request to a JavaScript function as follows: hence I am using Angular JS

```
  $scope.issueVideoUploadRequest = function () {

    var requestVideoUploadParameters = {
        videoSource: $scope.videoSource,
        title: $scope.title,
        description: $scope.description,
        videoLanguage: $scope.language,
        tagsList: $scope.tagsList
    };
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: requestVideoUploadParameters,
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/OampSeniorProjectV2/rs/content/requestUploadForm'
    }).success(function (response, status, headers) {
        $scope.alertMessageVideoRequest = response;
        alert(response);
    }).error(function (response, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.reloadPage();
    });
};
```

The form is submitted to a REST services.

The question is, where to find the g-recaptcha-response parameter so I send it back to the server along with the form JSON object? As I need this response value to perform the server side user verification.

I was following the documentation posted [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

grecaptcha.getResponse(widget_id);

This will give you the response of the recaptcha. Use this in your form submit function if you're using Angular.

Comment: Sorry but where does this `widget_id` come from?

Comment: @Blaise the ```widget_id``` is optional if you leave it blank it will give you the first widget.   

More information is available here    
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param

Comment: var response = window.grecaptcha.getResponse();

Comment: its in the documentation now, not sure if it was back then: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify